# Utilizing python code within swift using 3rd party software

Tags: python, ios, swift, xcode, swift-pythonkit

so I'm pretty new to both swift and stack, but I have a problem with implimenting Pythonkit. But basically to provide a short summary, the kit basically allows you to be able to utilize python inside of swift (using certain swift functions in order to save variables, do functions, however, can execute the code of a .py file).
In the process of doing this however this error pops up

```
Fatal error: Python library not found. Set the PYTHON_LIBRARY environment variable with the path to a Python library.: file /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Y******L-
```

So I tried updating my Python software to 3.0 and above (I'm not quite sure, I think it was 3.7), however when I run python it shows it is at version 2.7. This kind of confused me a bit, however it was until the error did I notice something was wrong. Why does it show that error? What does it mean? 
[(I did find a similar post with a similar error in stack overflow, however I don't have enough reputation to comment as well as I don't think the answer was addressed to what I wanted so I'm just going to continue writing here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126337/i-cant-import-python-modules-in-xcode-11-using-pythonkit)
The swift code itself has updated (xcode11) and following the steps a lot of the functions have changed within Xcode, what is it that I did wrong that caused the error? Following the link it seems I have to utilize pyto? Checking that link the functions of pyto are different than the ones pf PythonKit. In PythonKit you can utilize python within your swift code, while pyto seems to be a python integration for iOS?
Any advice? And please ask if anything needs clarification, or if there's a different solution please tell me. Thanks,Vince