# PythonKit error "Python library not found. Set the PYTHON_LIBRARY environment variable with the path to a Python library"

Tags: python, ios, xcode, spacy, swift-pythonkit

I'm using PythonKit with XCode to call spaCy API from swift code. Installed PythonKit from Home-brew, imported it in my project and it built well; however, at runtime I got the error:

```
Python library not found. Set the PYTHON_LIBRARY environment variable with the path to a Python library.
```

So I compiled PythonTools (within PythonKit dir, run `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and open PythonKit.xcodeproj file ) to see which paths of Python library it would find:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/Users/fernandabrum/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

If Python libraries are in my system, why I get an error of Python library not found? What am I doing wrong?

`OBS.:`I also tried to set PYTHON_LIBRARY with `export PYTHON_LIBRARY=` and the paths found above, but unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Also curious if you got this worked out. In my case I'm trying to load python 3.8 on Ubuntu. I've tried `PythonLibrary.useVersion(3)` and `PythonLibrary.useLibrary(at: "/usr/bin/python3.8")`, as well as the linuxbrew install, but nothing other than the `/usr/bin/python` (2.17) version works.

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved this problem, in my case, by setting `App Sandbox` to `NO` in my app's `.entitlements` file. I also have `Hardened Runtime` and `Enable App Sandbox` set to `NO` in build settings, but those settings **don't** work without modifying the entitlements file... at least not in my case.

My understanding is that I can't distribute an app this way, so maybe kinda useless for some, but this is just a simple dev tool for testing some python code that will eventually be called from Vapor, so not a huge deal for me.

Comment: It will stop you from sharing app to appstore. I have seen mutiple files on app store running python. How to run that on distributed app?

Answer (score 1):

In "Hardened Runtime" under Signing and Capabilities: check "Disable Library Validation"
See the answer here: [I can't import Python modules in Xcode 11 using PythonKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126337/i-cant-import-python-modules-in-xcode-11-using-pythonkit)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the python library does not support iOS yet. It is working fine on OS X.